# MongoDB - Connections vs. sessions

Tags: database, mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine, dbconnection

I tried to understand what is the difference between connection and session upon mongoDB connection. I do understand that sessions are stored in cache on the db side, and cleaned up per 5 minutes (configurable).
What the purpose of sessions? What would happen if I will use the same session for multiple queries (for different collections)
I read this excellent post about sessions:
https://www.percona.com/blog/2021/06/03/mongodb-message-cannot-add-session-into-the-cache-toomanylogicalsessions/

Im using mongoengine and pymongo clients.

Please help me understand it. Thanks.